# is this sentence using "but instead" correctly?

Tags: grammar

Someone who is beating around the bush is a person who avoids the main point of what they are saying, but instead talk around it.

I am doubting this sentence because it just sounds weird to have "avoids the main point" and then the use of "but instead" and "talk around it"

Would it be correct if you substitute "doesn't get to the gist" instead of "avoids the main point"?

Answer (score 2):

There’s nothing wrong with *but instead*. It sounds weird, because the verb should be *talks* and not *talk*. Its subject is *who*, which in turn stands for the singular *a person*, so the verb needs to be third person singular,  just like *avoids*. It would also be preferable for the coordinator to be *and* rather than *but*.

Comment: Should be *talks* not *talk.* I think you have misplaced the two.

Answer (score -1):

It seems weird indeed, because the metaphors are inconsistent : "point" is geometric, "talk" is about speech.

"Doesn't get to the gist" could mean "has not understood" instead of "doesn't want to be direct".

I would suggest "... avoid the gist ... but is evasive instead".

Nota : "but ... instead" is slightly pleonastic.

Comment: -1 Why are you comparing 'point' and 'talk'? The verbs are 'talk' & 'avoid'; the subjects are identical: 'main point' & 'it'. Also, "Doesn't get *to* the gist" does not mean "has not understood" - that would be "Doesn't *get the* gist".